# Capybara / poltergeist / phantomjs double_click missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, phantomjs, rspec-rails, poltergeist

Like the title says capybara is having trouble finding double_click:

```
undefined method `double_click' for #<Capybara::Node::Element:...>
```

Click works just fine as do most other methods.  I'm using capybara 2.1.0, poltergeist 1.6.0 and phantomjs 1.9.7.  Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It may help if you add some code snippets to your question so people can analyze. Right now, they have to guess.

Comment: I think maybe you can check your plugins version, make sure it's lastest, it's a solution sometimes...

Comment: I upgraded to capybara 2.4.4 and now I get not implemented:

`base.double_click
     NotImplementedError:
       NotImplementedError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity here's the solution:

I set javascript_driver:

`Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist`

but not default_driver:

`Capybara.default_driver = :poltergeist`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have a valid Capybara element that can be clicked on?

```
page.find('#lst-ib').double_click
```

The above works on Google.com

Answer (score 0):

For double click event, the below approach might help you solve your problem.
I know its bit late but for people who might face similar issue in their automation work

On latest ruby capybara and selenium version use

```
element = page.find(:xpath,"//a[contains(text(), locator)]")
page.driver.browser.action.double_click(element.native).perform
```

for Old version pls use the below code:

```
element = page.find(:xpath,"//a[contains(text(), locator)]")
page.driver.browser.mouse.double_click(element.native)
```

1. Find the element with either xpath or css.
2. Use `page.driver.browser.mouse.double_click(element.native)` to perform the action